# Archive artifacts in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have issue with archiving folder path in jenkins. I want only to archive what is inside my projects debug folder. I use following to do that.

```
MyApp1/MyApp1/bin/Debug/*
```

When I use that it will archive what inside debug folder but keep the same folder structure (MyApp1/MyApp1/bin/Debug).
If I only need t archive the files inside debug (Debug/) folder what shoud I do.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot remove the 'prefix' of a path using just the archive artifacts setting. (Some of the upload extensions do support this - the Publish over FTP plugin for example)

If you really need this a simple solution is to add an extra build step that copies your Debug folder to the root of the project workspace.

Answer (score 11):

A cleaner way might be to have a stage dedicated to producing artifacts, set up with the appropriate working directory:

```
    stage('Release') {
        steps {
            dir('MyApp1/MyApp1/bin/Debug') {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**', fingerprint: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me be cause my Jenkins didn't know the 'steps' command. I removed the steps block and just put the dir command into the stage. I also struggled with it because the path in the 'dir' command was invalid but it didn't complain about it.

Comment: @Chaoste This answer is for declarative pipelines; my guess is that you're using a scripted one.

Comment: This can also be placed in `post` instead of defining an extra stage: `post {
success { dir('MyApp1/MyApp1/bin/Debug') { archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**' }}}`

Answer (score 2):

I created a method to achieve this:

```
def archiveFilesWithoutPath(globPattern) {
    def files = findFiles(glob: globPattern)
    for (def i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        def file = files[i]
        def parentFolder = new File(file.path).getParent()
        dir(parentFolder) {
            archiveArtifacts file.name
        }
    }
}
```

Is is used like this:

```
archiveFilesWithoutPath '**/build/libs/*.jar'
```

The only downside currently is that you need to allow

```
new java.io.File java.lang.String
```

and

```
method java.io.File getParent
```

In the script approval.

Comment: Another downside is added steps logging in console and slower build times, especially when archiving many artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy! You can use plugins as like as "[File Operations](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin)" Plugin.
After installing it, you must add a new "build step" after all build steps, which name is File operations. There are a lot of options as you like.
For example "File Rename", "Copy File", "Make Folder", and etc.

"Copy File" option with "Flatten" switch, capable you to copy file only with its name without any file address. You can use that and copy your files in the root of workspace and archive them.

Answer (score -2):

If its Visual Studio, you can read the solution, find the project file, and from there you can find the output dir.